# If $R$ is a finitely generated $D$-algebra, $D$ a division ring, then $R$ has finite basis over $D$?

Tags: field-theory, division-algebras, free-modules, division-ring

Let $k \subset D \subset R$, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero,
$D$ is a division $k$-algebra, and $R$ is affine over $D$ (= $R$ is a finitely generated $D$-algebra).

$R$ is a free $D$-module, since $D$ is a division ring (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424025/dimension-of-division-rings-extension?noredirect=1&lq=1)),
so $R$ has a basis, finite or infinite, over $D$.

> Is the assumption that $R$ is affine over $D$ implies that $R$ has a finite basis as a $D$-module?

Is the fact that $D$ is Noetherian helps? (a division ring has no left ideals except the zero ideal, so it is trivially Noetherian).

My motivation is a similar result in field theory that says that an algebraic field extension which is finitely generated is finite dimensional.
Perhaps here I should further assume that $R$ is left algebraic over $D$, and only then get a positive answer?

Any comments are welcome!

**Edit:** The following is true: If $R$ is affine over a division ring $D$ (=finitely generated as a $D$-algebra) and also $R$ is left algebraic over $D$, then $R$ is finitely generated as a $D$-module.
The proof is as in the commutative case, with one exception:
We need to be careful on which side we multiply; more specifically,
if $d_m r^m+d_{m-1}r^{m-1}+\cdots+d_1r+d_0=0$ with minimal $m$, then
$r^m= -d_m^{-1}(d_{m-1}r^{m-1}+\cdots+d_1r+d_0)$,
from which it follows that $1,r,\ldots,r^{m-1}$ are generators for $D[r]$ over $D$
(indeed, higher powers of $r$ are $D$-linear combinations of 
$1,r,\ldots,r^{m-1}$-- multiply by $r$ on the right both sides etc.).
Finally, it is not difficult to see that the tower of finitely generated modules $D \subset D[r_1] \subset D[r_1,r_2]
 \ldots \subseteq D[r_1,\ldots,r_l]=R$ (not necessarily free modules) is also a finitely generated module.

Comment: No, it is not even true if $D=k$, e.g. a polynomial ring. See [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/280218/11323)

Comment: @Kimball, thanks, but what if $R$ is left algebraic over $D$? Is the proof for fields can be adjusted to the non-commutative setting ?

Comment: What does left algebraic over $D$ mean?

Comment: It means that every element of $R$ is left algebraic over $D$. An element $r \in R$ is left algebraic over $D$ if there exist $d_m,\ldots,d_1,d_0 \in D$ such that $d_mr^m+\cdots+d_1r+d_0=0$ (the coefficients are on the left. Similarly, right algebraic is when the coefficients are on the right: $r^md_m+\cdots+rd_1+d_0=0$).